# Google OAuth 2.0 cannot login/logout in production

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js, google-oauth, cookie-session

The login/logout functions work perfectly in development. However, after deploying it to heroku, the browser caches data and will stay logged in and the log out button just refreshes the page. I could clear browser cache data and it would allow me to login properly but then the same situation proceeds. Sometimes vice versa happens and the login button refreshes the page. I'm not sure what I did wrong. Please help and thanks in advance!

I'm still pretty new to using passport and here is the relevant code:

My index.js

```
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // cookies expire in 1 day
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

My passport.js

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => done(null, user));
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      proxy: true
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
          new User({ googleId: profile.id })
            .save()
            .then(user => done(null, user));
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

My authRoutes.js

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      scope: ['profile', 'email']
    })
  );

  app.get(
    '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google'),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );

  app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.session = null;
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue is because of the service worker that is packaged with Create-React-App. It intercepts /api routes and sends it to React-Router, in other words it's not being let through to the be handled by Express.

Now this is all assuming that you are actually using Create-React-App.

In your client side main index.js

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
```

then call the function before render().

```
unregister();

ReactDOM.render(

    <Provider store={store}> 

        <App/>

    </Provider> , 

     document.getElementById('root'));
```

Make sure to clear your cache and hard reload on your browser. It may 24 hours for the cache  to be invalidated.

Hope this helps!